# Accessing Data in a String List Array

Tags: c#

I have got two table in my database in which I am querying from, one named QuestionsTable and AnswersTable.

I am querying questionIDs from the AnswersTable and storing the ID's in a string array. like this:

```
List<string> questionId  = new List<string>();


       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           Query = "SELECT * FROM TblAnswers WHERE UserId = '1'";
           theReader = conn.ExecuteStatement(Query);
           while (theReader.Read())
           {

               questionId.Add(theReader["QuestionId"].ToString());


           }
```

To access these ID's stored in this array, I am doing this:

```
String Id = questionId[0];


           Query = "SELECT *  FROM QuestionsTable WHERE Id = '" + Id + "'";
           theReader = conn.ExecuteStatement(Query);
           while(theReader.Read())
           {
              question = theReader["Question"].ToString();

           }
```

In case described above I am only querying one question that "User 1" attempted but my main issue is that , lets that "User 1" attempted 10 questions and I would like to query and access the 10 questions' ID's from the string array, will I have to define 10 variables in order to access each and every QuestionID? e.g will I have to do this:

```
String Id = questionId[0];
String Id2 = questionId[1];
String Id3 = questionId[2];
String Id4 = questionId[3];
```

and so on up to 10...

Isn't there an easier way I can access these ID's without defining 10 variables?

I hope this makes sense and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a simple solution,

you may define a list of strings to hold the question, and iterate over all Ids, query each question alone and at last add this question to the defined list.

example:

```
List<string> qustions = new List<string>();
foreach(var id in questionId)
{
           Query = "SELECT *  FROM QuestionsTable WHERE Id = '" + id + "'";
           theReader = conn.ExecuteStatement(Query);
           while(theReader.Read())
           {
              question = theReader["Question"].ToString();
              qustions.add(question);
           }

}
```

Comment: I think this will work .. I shall give it a try as soon as I get near my laptop

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace the ID with questionId[i]. For example:

```
Query = "SELECT *  FROM QuestionsTable WHERE Id = '" + questionId[0] + "'";
```

I'm not quite sure what database software you are using. But I would also look into the IN command for SQL. That will let you test against a list of values instead, of just looking for one specific value. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682(SQL.90).aspx